# How to build Android packages/apps in side Android Studio.Any other way to build this apps

Tags: android, android-studio, android-source

I tried to import android AOSP packages/apps in Android Studio but the  build failed due to "Framework aidl files import". 
Kindly help me regrading this issue on how to build an AOSP app with Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

For the most part it's gonna be difficult. But:

- If that app uses some hidden APIs that are not in the public SDK, you
  can use a custom android.jar from this link :
  https://github.com/anggrayudi/android-hidden-api
- If it HAS to have system privileges, create a keystore from platform key, and use that in gradle signing.
- If it is dependened on some other module in AOSP, you can either do the migration with it first, and then try to add it as dependency, or just give up at this point.

How easy/difficult is using AOSP app in Android Studio it's gonna depend on case by case basis. Try it and ask a more specific question